# Flexible block positioning in Django?

Tags: django, django-templates

In `Drupal` you could choose in which "region" of your site you want your block displayed. You did not have to modify any `php/html` code in order to achieve this.
Can such a thing be achieved with `Django`, and if yes, how?

By block I understand a piece of `html` output that doesn't have it's own URL and gets displayed along side the main data. (for example a search box or a poll)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Hm you probably want to create context processor and just output from it where you want it in template?

If you want reordering of content blocks in html output inside admin then you need something to generate that output like cms. You could try something like [django-fluent-contents](https://github.com/edoburu/django-fluent-contents/) for this without requiring big cms.

Answer (score 2):

Django and Drupal shouldn't be compared like this: Drupal is a CMS, Django is a web framework.

If you want to get a somewhat similar experience, I would look at using [django-cms](https://www.django-cms.org/). With this, you can create numerous `templates` and set `placeholders` within these templates (these are regions of the page like 'sidebar', 'footer', 'content area' etc.). When you go to create a new page in django-cms, you select which template you want to use (maybe a two column layout or a three column layout with a header - depending on what you have created) and then you choose what content (or `plugins`) you want to place within the placeholders you have created in the template. So this is a somewhat similar experience to Drupal's regions.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm not comparing anything. Think that my question can sound something like: I have a small piece of html output, can I have flexible positioning for it in the template?

Comment: You won't really be able to achieve this with plain Django as you need to manually specify in the template where you want that html field to be outputted. You could create a `position` field or something similar and use that to choose where the content should be displayed in the template, but that's not very reuseable

Comment: Whell, then I propose a new principle to the Django developers along side the "do not repeat yourself" principle: "never assume" :)

Comment: I had the same confusion when using Drupal after Django as I was used to having to write a lot more to get things done, as opposed to in Drupal where you can get great results without having to do as much.

Comment: It's not the fact that I have to write that annoys me. I chose Django because I love python, I don't like restrictions and I want complete control. This is the second thing that bugs me. It's ok for a CMS to assume stuff but not for a framework.

Comment: Maybe you can write some custom tag and then display the content of that tag in the rest of the template? It's breaking the DRY principle but at least you don't repeat the whole html stuff in every "region"

Comment: Django isn't assuming anything. In fact, your frustration is coming from the fact that it *doesn't* assume. Your template could be HTML, JSON, XML, plain text, a PDF, whatever. Django gets out of your way and let's you format the data however you want.

Comment: Django assumes that you don't need flexible positioning of blocks. Isn't that a BIG assumption? What does the fact that it doesn't impose a specific format has to do with my question?